How to perform write operations after calling a @Transactional(readOnly = true) method in Spring Boot?
I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I have a method marked with @Transactional(readOnly = true) that retrieves data from the database. However, after calling this method, I need to perform a write operation, and this is causing a problem. The write operation fails because the previous method runs in a read-only transaction, and I get a MySQL error indicating that the transaction is read-only.
I cannot modify the existing method as it is used in many places across the application, and changing it to a regular transaction would break other use cases. Here's a simplified version of the code:
/* Called in a service called recService */
Obj obj = objService.getByObjId(objId);

// Write operation – this is where it breaks because the getByObjId was readOnly
if (obj) {
    // obj2Data is coming from argument
    obj2Data.set(c + 1);
    obj2Repository.save(p);
}


@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Obj getByObjId(Long objId) {
    Optional<Obj> obj = objRepository.findById(objId);
    if (obj.isPresent()) {
        obj.get().setE();
        obj.get().setE2();
        return obj.get();
    }
    return null;
}


What I've Tried:
I considered creating a new method without readOnly = true, but this leads to code duplication, which I'd like to avoid.
I know removing readOnly = true would fix the problem, but this is not an option as it impacts other areas.

Your encapsulating service method should be transactional not the individual ones, which would override the readOnly from the other one (as there would already be an ongoing transaction). Also stop abusing Optional like you do. use orElseGet(null) instead of an isPresent() check, you are doing a glorified null check which is discouraged (and actually called an anti pattern by the JDK devs).

Perhaps consider a coded transaction approach, which allows for more fine-grained management of transactions. Here's the sample code
//Injected bean
private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

public Object reedOnly() {
    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    
    //set ReadOnly
    transactionTemplate.setReadOnly(true);
    
    return transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
        //do something
        //return result
        return new Object();
    });
}

